# Crear un editor IndexedDB para almacenar valores en una base de datos NoSQL en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, local-storage, nosql, indexeddb

Tengo hecho un editor BBCode en JavaScript pero necesito que esos valores introducidos (en principio solo un valor que sea el nombre de una fruta) se almacenen en una base de datos NoSQL con usando IndexedDB y LocalStorage, el problema es que estoy bastante perdido en el tema y no se por donde empezar, voy a poner por aqui lo que tengo y a ver si me vais diciendo porque me parece complicado el tema...

```js
FRUTA.namespace('FRUTA.IndexeDB');
(function(g){
    'use strict';
    FRUTA.IndexeDB.localDatabase = {};

    FRUTA.IndexeDB.inicializa = function(){
        FRUTA.IndexeDB.localDatabase.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
        FRUTA.IndexeDB.localDatabase.IDBKeyRange = window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange;
        FRUTA.IndexeDB.localDatabase.IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction;

        FRUTA.IndexeDB.localDatabase.indexedDB.onerror = function (e) {
            console.log("Database error: " + e.target.errorCode);
        };
    };
    FRUTA.IndexeDB.openDB = function(dbName, version){
        var openRequest = FRUTA.IndexeDB.localDatabase.indexedDB.open(dbName,version);
        openRequest.onerror = function(e) {
            console.log("Database open error: " + e.target.errorCode);
        };
        openRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
            FRUTA.IndexeDB.localDatabase.db = openRequest.result;
        };

    };


})(window);
```

Comment: A ver si asi esta mejor....